# What does "picked a sweet bung of a time" mean?

Tags: meaning

In *Serenity (2005)*, a very dangerous enemy called the "Reavers" are about to break into the room. River, by far their best fighter and only hope against the Reavers, is in the corner having a mental breakdown, clutching her head:

> River: The Reavers. They are all made up of rage. I can't shut them up.

So Jayne critizes River:

> Jayne: She **picked a sweet bung of a time** to go helpless on us.

What does "picked a sweet bung of a time" mean?

Comment: There could be some Western state where this is an expressions. I certainly have never seen it. Think of it as: She picked a hell of a time to go helpless on us. When writers want to avoid clichés, what they use is sometimes worse than the cliche....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's more Firefly slang invented by the series writers.

*"Bung"*, or more commonly *"bunghole"*, is an English word that can mean "*asshole*", but in the Firefly universe, "bung" is used as a replacement for "fuck". An example of its use earlier in the movie:

> Mal: There's a lot of fine ways to die. And I ain't waiting for the Alliance to choose mine. I mean to confound those ***bungers***.

So the equivalent of that phrase in real English would be: "*picked a sweet fuck of a time*".

This English expression is highly colloquial, and nearly always used sarcastically. Here, it means that this is an extremely inconvenient time for River to go helpless on them, when they're about to be killed by the Reavers.

Comment: The slang in English for that is: to take one's sweet ass time.

Comment: @Lambie - decidedly _American_ English, I would say.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Ah, Michael, right you are.

Comment: In UK informal English a bung is usually a bribe.

Comment: @Lambie To "**take** one's sweet (ass) time" means to do something slowly, with lack of concern for others' timelines. To "**pick** a sweet (ass) time" means the timing is bad. These are not the same thing. In this context, it definitely means bad timing, not taking too long. I've added some context in the OP, if that helps

Comment: Also I've changed my answer to what I think is a better interpretation